# In passive voice, Is using "by" after verb a rule?

Tags: grammar, active-voice

I am learning how to change Active Voice to Passive Voice.

Consider the following:

> He pleases everybody

```
Everybody is pleased by him/Everybody is pleased with him.
```

> Your behavior surprises me.

```
I am surprised by your behavior/ I am surprised at your behavior.
```

In both example I think the latter one is correct. So how will I know whether by is correct or some other preposition is to be used.

I mean does it depend on the context and verb?

Please clarify>

Comment: Passives typically have _by_ phrases. The others are not passives.

Comment: @BillJ: Isn't the passive voice defined by the use of "to be (conjugated) + pastParticipleOfOtherVerb"? I think they are all passive voice, even without using "by".

Comment: @virolino Yes, but the subject of the active appears in the passive as the complement of the preposition _by_ , not "with". "Everybody is pleased with him", "pleased" is not a past participle, but an adjective, c.f. "Everybody is very pleased  with him".

Comment: What about "It was made with a hammer"? "I was very made" - definitely sounds non-English.