# "I am delighted by or with the food" or "the food delighted me"

Tags: word-usage

**Can I say? "I am delighted by or with the food" or "the food delighted me"**

I wonder if it is correct and usual to say "I am delighted by or with the food" or " the food really delighted me" to compliment a delicious food that I ate and enjoyed its' taste and hence pleased by it.

If not, what is the most correct and usual way to express above situation by English native speakers?

Thank you

Comment: "The food was delightful!"

Comment: See also [In passive voice, Is using "by" after verb a rule?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/203358/in-passive-voice-is-using-by-after-verb-a-rule) and [I got upset {with / from} the phone call.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/237746/i-got-upset-with-from-the-phone-call)